# how to find the coordinates of the intersection point of a line ( parallel to a given line) and other line

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, shapely

I have 3 point A, B, C in the link. The points generate a triangle ABC.2 red lines parallel to AB and distance between them is 30. the green line passes through B and is perpendicular to AC. [here is picture to describe it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ0Lk.png)

How can I find the coordinate between 2 red lines and the green line

### solution

Thank you @MBo, and I want to provide an easier way to understand in the last expression:
I will put the ip1 coordinate as

```
ip1 = b.x + t * n.x, b.y + t * n.y                                     (1)
```

So the distance between ip1 and b will be:

```
d / sine(n, BA) = sqrt ((t * n.x) ** 2 + (t * n.y) ** 2)
```

You can calculate t easily and after that put it in the  (1) to find ip1 and ip2 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want two intersection points between height `Bh` and red lines (parallel to `BA` at distance `d`):

[image]

Get vectors

```
AC = C.x - A.x, C.y- A.y
BA = A.x - B.x, A.y- B.y
```

and normalize them ((make unit length dividing components by vector magnitude)

Get height vector as perpendicular to  AC as

```
n = -ac.y, ac.x
```

Find sine of angle between `n` and `BA` using cross product

```
s = abs(n.x * ba.y - n.y * ba.x)
```

Now get coordinates of intersection points:

```
ip1 = B + n * d / s
ip2 = B - n * d / s
```

That's all.

Comment: woow, I didn't know that there is a fast way to calculate intersection like your last expression, it has become much easier, thanks a lot for that. But I think in the second code block, it should be ac.x instead of ax.x, right?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: @Quân nguyễn It is not an answer so far?

Comment: sorry for rejecting your answer but I think that the expression to find sine is not true and when I correct it, I find out that the distance between them is not true

Comment: Sine expression is correct. Have you normalized ac and ba vectors before expression calculation?

Comment: BTW, I saw rejecting accidentally - there is no messages about this. So it is worth to write and inform about possible mistakes to correct them.

Comment: sorry for that, at that time, I forgot replying you because I was figuring out why. And I just found that the sine expression must be like this:                                              
abs(n.x * ba.y - n.y * ba.x) / (math.sqrt(n.x ** 2 + n.y ** 2) * math.sqrt(ba.x ** 2 + ba.y ** 2))

Comment: Seems you missed this line: `and normalize them ((make unit length dividing components by vector magnitude)`. So all needed information was in the answer.

Comment: oh, I don't really understand normalize it, but now I understand it, thanks @MBo